# Skip parent function if case is equal to 'merge' in PHP

Tags: php

I have a `try catch` statement with `switch` statement inside.

I'm kind of new into PHP so please bear with me. I know that this might be so simple for the PROS.

What I would like to achieve is to skip the first 2 `if` statements on top if `case is 'merge'`

```
try {
    if (!make_thumbnail($videoFile, $thumbLocal))
        throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);
    if (!put_file($thumbLocal, $thumbRemote))
        throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
    switch($message->priority) {
        case 'mp4':
            make_mp4($videoFile, $mp4file);
            if (!file_exists($mp4file))
                throw new \Exception($mp4file);
            if (!put_file($mp4file, $remotemp4))
                throw new \Exception($remotemp4);
            send_ready_ping($message->ping, $message->id, VIDEO_MP4);
            make_webm($videoFile,$webmfile);
            if (!file_exists($webmfile))
                throw new \Exception($webmfile);
            if (!put_file($webmfile, $remotewebm))
                throw new \Exception($remotewebm);
            send_ready_ping($message->ping,$message->id,VIDEO_BOTH);
            break;
        case 'merge':
            make_merged_video($videoFile, $audioFile, $mp4file, $message->options);
            if (!file_exists($mp4file))
                throw new \Exception($mp4file);
            if (!put_file($mp4file, $remotemp4))
                throw new \Exception($remotemp4);
            send_ready_ping($message->ping, $message->id, VIDEO_MP4);
            break;
        default;
            make_webm($videoFile,$webmfile);
            if (!file_exists($webmfile))
                throw new \Exception($webmfile);
            if (!put_file($webmfile, $remotewebm))
                throw new \Exception($remotewebm);
            send_ready_ping($message->ping, $message->id, VIDEO_WEBM);
            make_mp4($videoFile,$mp4file);
            if (!file_exists($mp4file))
                throw new \Exception($mp4file);
            if (!put_file($mp4file, $remotemp4))
                throw new \Exception($remotemp4);
            send_ready_ping($message->ping,$message->id,VIDEO_BOTH);
            break;
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    send_ready_ping($message->ping, $message->id, VIDEO_FAIL);
}
```

I want to skip the thumbnail generator whenever `case` is equal to **'merge'**

These are the codes/events that I would like to skip:

```
  if (!make_thumbnail($videoFile,$thumbLocal))
      throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);
  if (!put_file($thumbLocal, $thumbRemote))
      throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
```

I tried to put it inside the switch statement something like this but didn't work:

```
if (case != "merge") {
    if(!make_thumbnail($videoFile, $thumbLocal))
        throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);
    if (!put_file($thumbLocal, $thumbRemote))
        throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably refactor and restructure but at the moment I don't have a suggestion for that.  Given the existing code:

```
if($message->priority != 'merge' && !make_thumbnail($videoFile,$thumbLocal))
    throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);

if($message->priority != 'merge' && !put_file($thumbLocal,$thumbRemote))
    throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
```

Comment: Okay thank you. I forgot that `$message->priority` is the solution in here. I'll try this one

Answer (score 2):

Your naming is a bit odd, what with `$message->priority` being tied to some action you're doing for that request and not really a priority for the message. But your solution should be easy, just wrap your two outer `if`s with a new test:

```
if ($message->priority != "merge") {
    if(!make_thumbnail($videoFile,$thumbLocal))
        throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);

    if(!put_file($thumbLocal,$thumbRemote))
        throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
}
```

And there you have it, nothing else needs to change. Your case can stay as is.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that I passed the value in switch statement really. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you necessarily need to check `$message->priority` in a case statement?

```
try
{
    if($message->priority != 'merge'){            
        if(!make_thumbnail($videoFile,$thumbLocal))
            throw new \Exception ($thumbLocal);

        if(!put_file($thumbLocal,$thumbRemote))
            throw new \Exception($thumbRemote);
    }
    switch($message->priority)
    {
        case 'mp4':
        make_mp4($videoFile,$mp4file);
        if(!file_exists($mp4file))
            throw new \Exception($mp4file);
        if(!put_file($mp4file,$remotemp4))
            throw new \Exception($remotemp4);
        send_ready_ping($message->ping,$message->id,VIDEO_MP4);

    ...

}
```